# "letter and key" security?

Tags: authentication

I'm sure there's a proper name for this, but I have no idea what it is.  When my family fled Europe, one of the remaining items are a letter and a key from a bank.  The general idea was that whomever has the letter and the key, was allow to open a box that then had ... something that is lost to history.  One family member went with the letter, and the other with the key.  The interesting thing for me about this system is that it does not matter who has either the letter or the key, but the letter is signed by a specific banker of record.

In modern cryptography, is there a similar system where there is two party authentication system for information where one party has a signed "letter", and the other party has an unsigned "key".

Comment: You mean multi-factor authentication? There's not necessarily a crypto component to it though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing ?

Comment: @Marc  I was more thinking about the escrow aspect.  You have a trusted 3rd party that doesn't have access to the information, but holds the information.  They also verify it's there, even if they cannot read it.  This is a bit more than secret sharing or multi-factor auth.   I'm literally hoping to reproduce the same system via physical objects that have a RFID tag.

Comment: I don't think this is equivalent: the bank definitely has access to the contents of any account and/or safe and is not proving anything until you ask for the contents themselves (as opposed to guarantee that the contents are still there). If you really want blind escrow, you might be talking about encrypted contents with [proof of space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_space), or even proof of space-time.

Comment: @bdegnan Can you expand on the RFID a bit? Certainly it is digitally possible to store something encrypted at a 3rd party, and then require authentication / authorization to gain access to it. But that's more a simple protocol than a cryptographic procedure. I also have a lot of trouble mapping it to "an object with an RFID tag". Maybe writing down the explicit requirements would help?